Powershell to pull wmic diskdrive information
I'm trying to find a powershell command that will list volumes of internal hard disks only.  I can run a wmic command for wmic diskdrive which gives me the MediaType, but not the volume.  I ran the command for wmic logicaldisk which gives me the drive letter, but not the Media type from the diskdrive.  It lists both internal and external drives as just Local Fixed Disk.  How can I combine the two within a powershell script to only pull Internal Fixed Drive volumes?

If I got you right this should be all you need: Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object -Property DriveType -EQ -Value 3

You don't need wmic if you are already using PowerShell (in fact, it's preferred not to use wmic as it's deprecated anyway).

You didn’t specify whether you’re using Windows PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell 7.*; this works on both:
Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3"|
    Select-Object -Property DeviceID,VolumeName

This will return the drive letter and the volume name for each internal drive.
The details of the Win32_LogicalDisk class are documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk
The DriveType values documented are



Description
Value




Unknown
0


No Root Directory
1


Removable Disk
2


Local Disk
3


Network Drive
4


Compact Disc
5


RAM Disk
6



Get-CIMInstance is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-5.1 for Windows PowerShell 5.1 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.4 for PowerShell 7.*

Hi Jeff,  I've tried this before in powershell and it still gives me USB External Drives which is why I was looking at wmic since it will list a USB external drive as External Hard Disk Media versus an internal drive which is listed as Fixed Hard Disk Media.   I've been trying to find a way to combine powershell with get-phyisicaldisk and get-partition to try to pull only the drive letter of internal hard drives.  Still a work in progress as I'm trying to "weed out" partitions that do not have a drive letter.

Are you specifically including the filter on DriveType? If you have USB external drives that are reporting as DriveType 3, it's likely because of drivers that the manufacturer uses that  try to emulate a local fixed disk instead of registering as removable.

get-volume | ? drivetype -eq fixed <#storage module#>

DriveLetter FriendlyName      FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------      -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
                              NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     82.12 MB    525 MB
C           DISK              NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      5.48 GB 118.73 GB
            PortableBaseLayer NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      7.49 GB      8 GB

